# How did this turn into a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Just curious, this question turned into a community wiki mighty fast and doesn't have the up votes or activity I typically see with community wikis

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178411/was-c-usability-tested-before-it-was-released

Comment: Check out the [revision history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/178415/revisions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The person who asked the question (and also provided both answers so far) individually made their answers into community wiki. It wasn't an automatic conversion - the question is not CW and any new answers won't be CW either.

Comment: Ah, didn't know you could make your answer into CW on your own.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa In the old days you could also turn your question into CW, but too many people abused it in order to sneak in sub par questions without a rep penalty, and now it's gone.